# Xenoverse 2 - How to get Goku's damaged gi for CaC

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse-2

The gi that was worn by Goku when he went Super Saiyan for the first time against Frieza. It's damaged and reveals the blue shirt underneath all battle damaged. Well, where can I find it? I've looked everywhere and the only damaged gi was the one against Raditz?